# Treegrid links and buttons not active if not visible in the active window

Tags: ajax, treegrid

The treegrid (treegrid.com), loads the data but the buttons and the links in the grid are not active when it is in the active window but bellow the visible content.

If I scroll the window to make it visible and refresh it works fine.

If i load it in the active window while visible it works.
If I resize the window so it is not showing and refresh the buttons and links in the grid no longer works.